# Struggling to query specific element among others with the same class name using .querySelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

So I'm trying to crawl a site using Puppeteer. All the data I'm looking to grab is in multiple tables. Specifically, I'm trying to grab the data from a single table. I was able to grab the specific table using a very verbose `.querySelector(table.myclass ~ table.myclass)`, so now my issue is, my code is grabbing the first item of each table (starting from the correct table, which is the 2nd table), but I can't find a way to get it to just grab all the data in only the 2nd table.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const myUrl = "https://coolurl.com";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 926
  });
  await page.goto(myUrl);

  let gameData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let games = [];
    let gamesElms = document.querySelectorAll('table.myclass ~ table.myclass');
    gamesElms.forEach((gameelement) => {
      let gameJson = {};
      try {
        gameJson.name = gameelement.querySelector('.myclass2').textContent;
      } catch (exception) {
        console.warn(exception);
      }
      games.push(gameJson);
    });
    return games;
  })
  console.log(gameData);
  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('table.myclass ~ table.myclass')` grabs all tables except the first one. `.querySelector(table.myclass ~ table.myclass)` returns only the first element that matches (which is the second table)

Comment: @marzelin thank you! Can't believe I didn't spot that.

Comment: @marzelin, Should be posted as an answer? :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of the following methods to select the second table:

```
let gamesElms = document.querySelectorAll('table.myclass')[1];
let gamesElms = document.querySelector('table.myclass:nth-child(2)');
```

Additionally, you can use the example below to push all of the data from the table to an array:

```
let games = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table.myclass:nth-child(2) tr'), e => {
  return Array.from(e.querySelectorAll('th, td'), e => e.textContent);
});

// console.log(games[rowNum][cellNum]); <-- textContent
```

Comment: This works great thank you! I was curious if you could clarify a little further exactly what is happening in your example? I was planning on going a completely different direction and the shorthand syntax is kind of throwing me a bit. If not, no worries.

Comment: @RyanMcguinn Sure! In the example, for each table row in the second table, I [mapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) arrays of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) from each row cell to the larger result array. The result is a 2D array which is indexed by row and then cell number (beginning with `0`).